# Keyboard shortcut to close documentation?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut that closes a documentation window opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>? The <kbd>ESC</kbd> key doesn't seem to work and googling was not successful for me either. I'm on OSX with the cross platform keyboard map if that's any help.

Comment: Just toying with ESC on my IntelliJ, and that seems to work fine...

Comment: ESC just makes the doc window go out of focus for me. Weird.

Comment: I just started using IntelliJ, and ESC worked for about 1 week. Then I changed *something*, and ended up requiring Shift-ESC. Annoying! I can't figure out what I changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shift-Escape should do the trick

Answer (score 27):

#### The Problem

As I stated in a comment,

> I just started using IntelliJ, and ESC worked for about 1 week. Then I changed something, and ended up requiring Shift-ESC. Annoying! I can't figure out what I changed.

I finally figured out why ESC stopped working. After an initial install of IntelliJ, the dialog is considered a "popup". If you open this popup with Ctrl+Q, and then click the pin icon at the upper right, it turns the popup into a normal dialog. This dialog behaves like the other views, which are dismissed with Shift+ESC.

#### The Fix

To restore the popup behavior, click the gear icon (upper right) and make sure "Show Toolbar" is checked. Click the big red X icon. This returns it to popup mode.

My life just got way better.

Comment: For me it was that "Pinned mode" was checked so I uncheked it.

Answer (score 3):

Just uncheck pin mode icon (upper right corner):

[image]

And then the doc window becomes a popup:

[image]

Then you can press Esc to dismiss it.

Comment: You know, qed, the Pin mode icon was introduced in IDEA 15... Older versions don't have this amazing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Shift-Esc is a helpful trick, but it does not solve the problem itself.
The problem is that the Documentation tool window is presented on the tool window bar. In order to close it, press Ctrl+Q 3 times (until the Documentation tool window disapears from the tool window bar). After that, Ctrl+Q will work as before.

Answer (score 1):

I had click on the pin because I didn't want a pop-up behavior. Then it's true that `Shift-Escape` doesn't do the trick (as stated in the windows) but you may use `Alt+F4` by following the below Fix.

**A Fix if you don't want a pop-up behavior but a windows behavior (Alt+F4 to close)**

In the `Upper right`,

1. Pin the windows by clicking on the Pin button
2. Click the gear icon and select "Windowed Mode"
3. Then Click the well-known `Alt+F4` to close the windows.

[image: Windowed Mode]